# displacement detail problem

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, displacement

I'm trying to set up some greeble panels and I keep getting these undulating faces when I use a displacement map. I am using a pretty high res 6000x6000 PNG to generate the displacement but I can't figure out why the faces aren't smooth. The subdivision level should be high enough to accommodate the details (its on level 4 with 10,000 polys to start) but it doesn't for some reason. This happens when I use the node render based displacement through cycles as well as the evee method with using subd and displacement modifier. Here are some screen shots to demonstrate what I am talking about.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a few possibly helpful pointers:

- Foremost, I have noticed that Blender doesn't always play nicely with .png files (especially with normals and displacements). Try a .tiff, or other type.
  I had the same issue of 'undulating surfaces', surfaces that should be smooth, but appear bumpy for no apparent reason.
- Second, I notice thin, horizontal rectangles in your second image. Check that your mesh geometry is composed of **squares**, not rectangles. Otherwise you'll experience issues when displacing or otherwise deforming the mesh.
- Lastly, double check that your UV's are unwrapped properly, same reason as above. If the UV is stretched in one direction and not another, it will distort the effect. *Not sure if this is the problem here but thought I'd suggest in case.*

One more thing: you might want to try using adaptive subdivision in this case.
Andrew Price does a good job explaining what it does and how to use it in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng) video.

I hope one of these helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Unfortunately after trying unwrapping again and remeshing and adaptive sub d and changing the displacement file type I am still getting the same result. I guess next I am going to try with different maps maybe just randos from the internet and see what happens.

Comment: Strange. However, that is a good idea to continue troubleshooting! If you want to post the .blend I may be able to help further.
Good luck!

Comment: Ok here's a google drive link to the .blend. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iu6IzzgQv5aEI82oWBKOeP8zs8xRLuvq/view?usp=sharing